# Split the education tag?

Tags: discussion, retagging

I think we have a tag being used for two separate types of questions, and so should probably split it.  The [education](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/education) tag is used for questions applying to both the education of end-users and non-IT-Security folks, as well as career-related education for IT Security professionals.  So, I suggest splitting the tag into two: [user-education](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/user-education) and [career-education](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career-education).

Below are some examples which I hope demonstrate the distinction between these two proposed tags.  The questions themselves may or may not be examples of "good" questions in general, but I think they do show how the same tag is being used for two significantly different purposes.

There may even arguably be need for a third tag or more, to cover [user-education](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/user-education) questions which are really more about educating non-Security IT folk, or management types, as opposed to regular end-users.

Examples:

[user-education](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/user-education)

[Why does one need a high level of privacy/anonymity for legal activities?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/7666/why-does-one-need-a-high-level-of-privacy-anonymity-for-legal-activities)
[Why do law-abiding citizens need strong security?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/7539/how-to-counter-the-statement-you-dont-need-strong-security-if-youre-not-doi)
[Doing a demo about open wireless networks exploiting with Firesheep](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1797/doing-a-demo-about-open-wireless-networks-exploiting-with-firesheep)
[How to define security requirements to ensure that developers... do not provide security by obscurity?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1581/how-to-define-security-requirements-to-ensure-that-developers-do-not-provide-s)
[How can I keep my programmer collegues informed about security issues?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1005/how-can-i-keep-my-programmer-collegues-informed-about-security-issues)
[What policies maximize employee buy-in to security?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/666/what-policies-maximize-employee-buy-in-to-security)
[What are good ways to educate about IT security in a company?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/507/what-are-good-ways-to-educate-about-it-security-in-a-company)
[What are a few good analogies to describe the benefits of a strong security program?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/357/what-are-a-few-good-analogies-to-describe-the-benefits-of-a-strong-security-progr)
[What are a few good lists of threats to use to kick-off conversations with others about what worries them?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/157/what-are-a-few-good-lists-of-threats-to-use-to-kick-off-conversations-with-others)

[career-education](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career-education)

[Courses on "Secure Software Development"](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1/courses-on-secure-software-development)
[Resources to learn about security](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/266/resources-to-learn-about-security)
[If you could have only one book on web security, what would it be?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/419/if-you-could-have-only-one-book-on-web-security-what-would-it-be)
[What security resources should a white-hat *developer* follow these days?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/571/what-security-resources-should-a-white-hat-developer-follow-these-days)
[What does a MCSE need to learn to be proficient regarding *nix security?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/771/what-does-a-mcse-need-to-learn-to-be-proficient-regarding-nix-security)
[How to get into RFID auditing?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1401/how-to-get-into-rfid-auditing)
[I see entry level security skills as a problem for industry - what can we do about it?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/i-see-entry-level-security-skills-as-a-problem-for-industry-what-can-we-do-abou)
[Good (preferably free) resource for CISSP practice questions](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1883/good-preferably-free-resource-for-cissp-practice-questions)
[Books about Penetration Testing](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2013/books-about-penetration-testing)
[CEH resources for exam prep](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2050/ceh-resources-for-exam-prep)
[Video Tutorials resources for IT Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2327/video-tutorials-resources-for-it-security)
[Should I go for Master of Science by GIAC SANS and what to do with my expiring GSEC cert?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2350/should-i-go-for-master-of-science-by-giac-sans-and-what-to-do-with-my-expiring-gs)
[Can you pass C|EH without any hands-on experience in hacking tools](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2628/can-you-pass-ceh-without-any-hands-on-experience-in-hacking-tools)
[CEH or GIAC - Which one should I pursue?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3752/ceh-or-giac-which-one-should-i-pursue)
[SANS training - worth it?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/5569/sans-training-worth-it)
[NSA CAE/IAE courses](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/5601/nsa-cae-iae-courses)
[Literature about IT security from a hardware standpoint](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6940/literature-about-it-security-from-a-hardware-standpoint)

Comment: I support this, educating users is a huge part of security and deserves its own tag.

Comment: What needs to be done to slipt the tag? Delete the old tag and add the new one?

Comment: Excellent idea - I support this! Any volunteers to create the tag and sort this out?

Comment: *grumble* I'm glad it's only 62 of them...

Comment: Good idea. Maybe "career-development" would be better than "career-education" though? Or "training"?

Comment: I was thinking [tag:professional-education] seemed like the better name for it.

Answer (score 3):

Alright, I went and retagged a bunch. Everything that is left in [education](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/education) is currently a [professional-education](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/professional-education) question. I think anything with [career-education](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career-education) (which I moved a bunch to) needs to be merged with that. Otherwise, [user-education](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/user-education) has been populated. So, tasks:

- Rename [career-education](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career-education) to [professional-education](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/professional-education)... probably by making that a synonym.
- Synonym [education](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/education) -> [professional-education](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/professional-education)

Comment: Done - apologies for the delay :-)